# Symfony service FileUploader not autowiring

Tags: symfony, file-upload, service

I've followed the Symfony 5.2 tutorial to add a FileUploader as a service (https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).

So this is my **service.yaml**

```
parameters:
  targetDirectory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'
  previews_video: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/previews'
  brochures_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/brochures'
services:
  App\Service\FileUploader:
      arguments:
          $targetDirectory: '%previews_video%'
```

And this is my **FileUploader.php**

```
<?php


namespace App\Service;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDirectory;
    private $slugger;

    public function __construct($targetDirectory, SluggerInterface $slugger)
    {
        $this->targetDirectory = $targetDirectory;
        $this->slugger = $slugger;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $safeFilename = $this->slugger->slug($originalFilename);
        $fileName = $safeFilename.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        try {
            $file->move($this->getTargetDirectory(), $fileName);
        } catch (FileException $e) {
            // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
        }

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDirectory()
    {
        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }
}
```

But I'm having this common error :

> Cannot resolve argument $fileUploader of "App\Controller\VideoController::edit()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\FileUploader": argument "$targetDirectory" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

Called by this controller :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="video_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Video $video
 * @param FileUploader $fileUploader
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Video $video, FileUploader $fileUploader): Response
{...}
```

How do I fix this ? I trying by remove the **string** type, adding the string type, removing the **$** from the **targetDirectory** parameters in services.yaml... Struggling with that for hours now...

Comment: Are your services configured to be autowired using `autowire: true`?

Comment: service.yaml or services.yaml?  Not doing any sort of bundle nonsense are you?  Does 'bin/console debug:container FileUploader' offer any clues?  And don't forget the magical clearing of the cache.

Comment: **services.yaml**, and already cleared the cache

Comment: You have something strange going on here.  I made a simple test case with your service.  Without changing anything in config/services.yaml I got the same error as you as expected.  I copied/pasted in your configuration and everything worked.  I thought maybe the fact that you had a parameter named targetDirectory might be the issue but it is not.  All I can suggest at this point is to make a new project, copy in your service and try injecting it.  Maybe double check that the Service directory has not been excluded from autowire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my working **services.yaml**. I've changed the namespace

> App\Service

to

> App\Services

And I also added the service declaration at the end of the file.

Looks like the order of the lines in **services** matter. First, I've added the declaration at the top of the **services** part, but the **autowiring** is declared after, guess the error was here...

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    previews_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/previews'
services:
  #i've added my service here at first... 
    app.menu_builder:
        class: App\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createMainMenu, alias: main }
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    App\Services\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            $targetDirectory: '%previews_directory%'
```

Comment: I had a tough time figuring out what I am doing wrong. Anyway, I have just found that if you use `#[AsController]` attribute on top of the controller w/o extending the AbstractController does work too. And also it requires to have `symfony/http-kernel` package installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a type-hint `string` for `$targetDirectory` in the contructor

```
public function __construct(string $targetDirectory, SluggerInterface $slugger)
{
    $this->targetDirectory = $targetDirectory;
    $this->slugger = $slugger;
}
```

Comment: Also tried to add **string** in constructor, still have an error

Answer (score 0):

You should have autowiring configuration added to your services file:

```
parameters:
  targetDirectory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'
  previews_video: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/previews'
  brochures_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/brochures'
services:
  # To add:
  _defaults:
      autowire: true
      autoconfigure: true
  # You service
  App\Service\FileUploader:
      arguments:
          $targetDirectory: '%previews_video%'
```

Comment: If autowire was not enabled then they would not have gotten an autowire error message.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, autowiring is enable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It was related to the indentation of that specific service. I wasn't getting any indentation error but also the auto wiring wasn't working.
What i did was to add 4 spaces as indentation

```
    App\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            $targetDirectory: '%TEAM_LOGO_DIRECTORY%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got the problem too and I managed to solve it by replacing indentation by spaces in the services.yaml file, I added all of these properties at the same root and then I did that and it works for me:

```
services:
    App\Services\FileUploader: #(added 4 spaces, NOT 1 tab)
        arguments: #(added 8 spaces, NOT 2 tabs)
            $targetDirectory: '%cats_directory%' #(added 12 spaces, NOT 3 tabs)
```

If you struggle you (and other people who got this problem) can try this solution. I don't guarantee it will work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue i finaly a release that i forget to capitalize the class App\Service\FileUploader it was App\Service\fileUploader